# Outlook 2007 show sender account in new mail window

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

#### How can I always show the sender's email account in the *New Mail* window of Outlook 2007?

This is easy to do in **Outlook 2010**.  The screenshot shows how the sender's address is always shown, without any user action required:
[image]

But in **Outlook 2007** I must click on the "Account" button to display the sender, which is extra work:

[image]

Is there an option or setting I am missing in Outlook 2007 which gives me the functionality described above for Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [TechRepublic blog post](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/quick-tip-show-the-from-and-bcc-fields-in-outlook/) you can turn on the **From:** field in Outlook 2007 by clicking the appropriate option on the *Options* tab of the ribbon:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's true you can turn it on, but Outlook still does not display the from address without additional user action (even when turned on).

Comment: I'm afraid this is as close as you can get in Outlook 2007. After all, you're asking about functionality that was *added* in the 2010 version.